# In vim, how to insert shell command output when executing contents of visual block

Tags: vim

With Vim, I often execute lines of a bash script  while editing it,
using `:'<,'>w !bash` after selecting the lines with visual block.

Now I want the output of command to be inserted in the script.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your code to be replaced with its output, you can simply remove the `w` from your command. That leaves you with:

```
:'<,'>!bash`
```

which acts like a filter for the selected lines. See `:help :!`.

If you want to insert the output of your code below itself like so:

```
echo 1
1
```

you will need to be a little bit creative:

```
:'<,'>t'>|'[,']!bash
```

- `:[range]t[address]` copies lines in `[range]` below line `[address]`. Here, we copy the visually selected lines below themselves.
- `|` separates Ex commands.
- `'[,']!bash` works like above: it filters the lines in the given range through `bash`. Here, the range covers the latest changed lines, in this case the lines we just copied. See `:help '[`.

Possible improvements…

- Make the command less noisy with `:help :silent`:

  ```
  :'<,'>t'>|sil'[,']!bash
  ```
- Prepend a comment character:

  ```
  :'<,'>t'>|sil'[,']!bash|sed 's/^/\# /'
  ```
- Turn it into a visual mode mapping:

  ```
  xnoremap <key> :t'>\|sil'[,']!bash\|sed 's/^/\# /'<CR>
  ```

Comment: Thank you great explanation. I wanted output to be inserted below. Possibly yanking the code lines and the replacing them may be easier albeit uglier.

Comment: That's essentially what the answer does, but in a slightly cleaner, less pedestrian way.